# Need Help in Perl looping

Tags: perl

I have a file with following data. I want to print in an external file with sum of every 9 rows. Here is my data.

file.xyz

```
-0.485718003092488 3.25568455554021 -0.60544991716881 
-1.01253068155602 -2.49251542491767 0.713923699625837
0.791137982988487 -2.56492609246597 -0.853251541212567
-0.485718003092488 3.25568455554021 -0.60544991716881
-1.01253068155602 -2.49251542491767 0.713923699625837
0.791137982988487 -2.56492609246597 -0.853251541212567
-0.485718003092488 3.25568455554021 -0.60544991716881
-1.01253068155602 -2.49251542491767 0.713923699625837
0.791137982988487 -2.56492609246597 -0.853251541212567
-0.485718003092488 3.25568455554021 -0.60544991716881
-1.01253068155602 -2.49251542491767 0.713923699625837
0.791137982988487 -2.56492609246597 -0.853251541212567
-0.485718003092488 3.25568455554021 -0.60544991716881
-1.01253068155602 -2.49251542491767 0.713923699625837
0.791137982988487 -2.56492609246597 -0.853251541212567
-0.485718003092488 3.25568455554021 -0.60544991716881
-1.01253068155602 -2.49251542491767 0.713923699625837
0.791137982988487 -2.56492609246597 -0.853251541212567
```

My output looks like

```
-2.121332105    -5.405270886    -2.234333276    6.221675693
-2.121332105    -5.405270886    -2.234333276    6.221675693
```

Where the first line is sum of 1-9 and second line is sum from 10-18. Here data are same for first 9 and last 9 rows, it gives same value. I want to print sum of EVERY NINE lines of big files with thousands line file.

Here is my code, it calculates the total sum, but I need to split into two parts as above.

Thank you for your help and appreciated.

```
my @sums;
open FILE, "file.xyz" or die "Can't find";

while( <FILE> ) { # there is FILE written within angular brackets
    my @summands = split / /;
    foreach my $i ( 0 .. $#summands ) {
        $sums[$i] += $summands[$i];
    }
}
$total = sqrt($sums[0]*$sums[0]+$sums[1]*$sums[1]+$sums[2]*$sums[2]);
print "$sums[0], $sums[1], $sums[2], $total\n";
```

Comment: I think you want the sum of every 9 rows, not columns. Better to use the three argument form of 'open' to open the file. You can use `$row_number % 9 == 0` to test whether the current row is divisible by 9.

Comment: Hello @sockmonk,
Yes, it is NOT columns, it's rows. Where do I add this? this is something I need it. I need a new loop which counts the lines and print until that and start the loop again...I am not good in programming.

Comment: Thank you Everyone . It means a lot to me...

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
open my $fh, '<', 'file.xyz';

my @sums;
my $n = 0;
while (<$fh>) {
    my @summands = split /\s+/;
    foreach my $i ( 0 .. $#summands ) {
        $sums[$i] += $summands[$i];
    }
    unless ( ++$n % 9 ) {
        my $total = sqrt( $sums[0] * $sums[0] + $sums[1] * $sums[1] + $sums[2] * $sums[2] );
        print "$sums[0], $sums[1], $sums[2], $total\n";
        @sums = ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a line counter and move the `$total` and `print` code into the loop under a conditional. You'll also need to clear the sums there.

```
if ($lines % 9 == 0) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Input line number, [`$.`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24.), to determine when your on every 9th line:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use List::Util qw(sum);

#open my $fh, '<', "file.xyz";
my $fh = \*DATA;

my @sums;

while (<$fh>) {
    my @cols = split ' ';
    for my $i ( 0 .. $#cols ) {
        $sums[$i] += $cols[$i];
    }

    if ( ( $. % 9 ) == 0 or eof ) {
        my $weighted_total = sqrt sum map $_**2, @sums;
        print join( ', ', @sums, $weighted_total ), "\n";
        @sums = ();
    }
}

warn "FH did not end an on even multiple of 9" if $. % 9;

__DATA__
-0.485718003092488 3.25568455554021 -0.60544991716881 
-1.01253068155602 -2.49251542491767 0.713923699625837
0.791137982988487 -2.56492609246597 -0.853251541212567
-0.485718003092488 3.25568455554021 -0.60544991716881
-1.01253068155602 -2.49251542491767 0.713923699625837
0.791137982988487 -2.56492609246597 -0.853251541212567
-0.485718003092488 3.25568455554021 -0.60544991716881
-1.01253068155602 -2.49251542491767 0.713923699625837
0.791137982988487 -2.56492609246597 -0.853251541212567
-0.485718003092488 3.25568455554021 -0.60544991716881
-1.01253068155602 -2.49251542491767 0.713923699625837
0.791137982988487 -2.56492609246597 -0.853251541212567
-0.485718003092488 3.25568455554021 -0.60544991716881
-1.01253068155602 -2.49251542491767 0.713923699625837
0.791137982988487 -2.56492609246597 -0.853251541212567
-0.485718003092488 3.25568455554021 -0.60544991716881
-1.01253068155602 -2.49251542491767 0.713923699625837
0.791137982988487 -2.56492609246597 -0.853251541212567
```

Outputs:

```
-2.12133210498006, -5.40527088553029, -2.23433327626662, 6.22167569349391
-2.12133210498006, -5.40527088553029, -2.23433327626662, 6.22167569349391
```

Answer (score -1):

The whole thing in Perl-golf style, watered down with a bit of whitespace and indentation:

```
while (<>) {
    @l = split;
    @s = map { $s[$_] + $l[$_] } 0..$#l;
    next if ++$n % 9;
    $, = ' ';
    print @s, sqrt(eval join '+', (map { $_*$_ } @s)), "\n";
    @s = ();
}
```

And some real Perl-golf, inspired by @Nemo, but even shorter:

```
perl -lanE '$s[$_]+=$F[$_]for 0..$#F;$.%9&&next;print"@s @{[sqrt eval join qq(+),map $_**2,@s]}";@s=()'
```

Finding the used tricks is left as an exercise to the readers. :-)

Comment: Golfing? `perl -MList::Util=sum -lanE '$s[$_]+=$F[$_]for 0..$#F;$.%9&&next;print"@s @{[sqrt sum map $_**2,@s]}";@s=()'`

Comment: I wonder whether I was downvoted by a strict-warnings zealot, or the rather brilliant winner of the golf competition, Nemo... :-)

Comment: I'm not downvoted you! Golfing is fun (maybe, not for SO) and i got many inspirations from your code ;).

Comment: `-lanE`, that was crazy! :-)